# Ubuntu thinks I'm out of space!

Tags: dpkg, pipe

I've got two Ubuntu boxes running who have both developed the same problem.

They keep throwing up error messages about how I'm out of space.

```
Error: BrokenCount > 0
```

Tried to run `sudo apt-get -f install`:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-83-generic_4.4.0-83.106_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/System.map-4.4.0-83-generic' to '/boot/System.map-4.4.0-83-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-83-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-83-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-83-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-83-generic
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-4.4.0-93-generic_4.4.0-93.116_amd64.deb ...
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-4.4.0-93-generic (4.4.0-93.116) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-93-generic_4.4.0-93.116_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-93-generic' to '/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-93-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-93-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-93-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-93-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-93-generic
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-4.4.0-96-generic_4.4.0-96.119_amd64.deb ...
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-4.4.0-96-generic (4.4.0-96.119) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-96-generic_4.4.0-96.119_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/System.map-4.4.0-96-generic' to '/boot/System.map-4.4.0-96-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-96-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-96-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-96-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-96-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-97-generic_4.4.0-97.120_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-83-generic_4.4.0-83.106_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-93-generic_4.4.0-93.116_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-96-generic_4.4.0-96.119_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Deleted a load of files, still wouldn't fix my dependencies. 
How'd my pipe break and what should I do to fix this?

`df`:

```
   Filesystem                  1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev                          3529056        0   3529056   0% /dev
tmpfs                          710068    17808    692260   3% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root 953106324 11889680 892778580   2% /
tmpfs                         3550320      800   3549520   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                            5120        4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                         3550320        0   3550320   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                      483946   474540         0 100% /boot
/dev/sda1                      523248     3664    519584   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs                          710068       84    709984   1% /run/user/1000
/home/frank/.Private        953106324 11889680 892778580   2% /home/frank
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: /BOOT is 100% full, It can't write any more kernels there, remove your old ones

Comment: @ravery should write an answer so I could upvote it :)

Answer (score 1):

your partition for /boot is 100% full.
Ubuntu can't write any ore kernels there.

You need to remove old unused kernels.